# How to store data typed by user into input using Django

Tags: javascript, django, web, storage

I'm kinda new to Django and I got stucked.

I want to get user input, and after that, I want to display a value that depends on it.

For example in Django I have if statement which checks input from the user, for the example car model.

So, when the user type is Ibiza I want to display "Seat", user type E92 I want to display "BMW" etc
I want to display car brands in the list that can be cleared or disappear after the user close the tab and re-open.

Which solution is the best? Database in Django? Cookies? Local storage in javascript?

Comment: You can use *AJAX* from the page based on the `onkeydown` event on the input to communicate with the server, where the django view you're communicating to checks the input against the database values and returns the desired values

Answer (score 0):

Use the Database. That way you have more control of the data.

Comment: Not answer for my question, i asked about storing values, not about how to take input from user.